# Почему не сработал on.click по элементу в bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему не сработал on.click по элементу в bootstrap modal?

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="idCV" name="file" value="" required>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(function(){
   $('input[type="radio"]').on('click', function(){
       alert('f');        
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, содержимое modal подгружается ajax-ом.

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function(){
       alert('f');        
   });
});
```